# find value for single quoted or double quoted id attribute regex

Tags: regex, search

I am trying to write a script which would crawl through the file tree and collect all the id attribute values (id="value"). I want to collect and list such values using regex. Here's what I came up with:

```
id=\'(.*?)\' - for singe quotes
```

and

```
id=\"(.*?)\" - for double quotes
```

What I'm trying to figure out is how could I merge these two into one, so it would find values wrapped in either single or double quotes.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is a very simple solution, [example here](https://regex101.com/r/poJH4G/2).

```
id=\'([^']*)\'|id=\"([^"]*)\"
```

Instead of `(.*)` looking for anything, the `([^']*)` looks for anything apart from an apostrophe.

Comment: If you know the exact format of the id, e.g. all numbers or all letters, it'd probably be better to specify it in the regex such as `([0-9]*)` .

Answer (score 1):

Use a backreference:

```
id=(["'])(.*?)\1
```

- Now captured group 2 (`(.*?)`) i.e. `\2` would have your desired value.
- `(["'])` matches any of `"` or `'` and put in captured group 1, `\1` at the end make sure we are looking for the same token as the first captured group

[Demo](https://regex101.com/r/sPg1pi/2)

Comment: I much prefer this solution - more elegant. If you were being pedantic, or combining it with other regex and wanted it to be safe, you could even try: `id=(["'])(?:(?!\1).)*\1`